# JS translate XMLHttpRequest to Fetch-function (GET): Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body

Tags: get, xmlhttprequest, fetch

How to convert old XMLHttpRequest based code to FETCH function?
An old code:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "username": "user",
  "token": "12345"
});
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:5000/v1/data/users/");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.send(data);
```

I can't send data-fields thro GET request

I have tryed:

```
fetch (url, {method: 'GET',
             mode:"cors",
             body: JSON.stringify({
               username,
               token
             }),
             headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
       })
```

but i have caught Fetch Error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.

Comment: It seems like the error message is pretty clear: GET requests can’t have a request body, but your code is trying to send a GET request with an `application/json` request body. Why are you trying do that? Why aren’t you just using a POST request instead?

Comment: Using the POST-request have to lead change back-end legacy code, it is not in my competence.
If i will have not solved at next week with FETCH-function, i will code a Promise-wrapper around XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Have you got an idea, how the POSTMAN doing that?
[get-header](https://yadi.sk/i/eSPE6jS0xRt0pw).
[get-body](https://yadi.sk/i/PsaA-LzMTk7HwA).

Comment: Postman is able to send GET requests that have a request body because like other general HTTP clients there are no restrictions on the characteristics of HTTP requests it can make. But the the case of the Fetch API, the Fetch spec places an explicit restriction on what kind of GET requests you can make with the API. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-requestinit-body%E2%91%A0: *“If either init["body"] exists and is non-null or inputBody is non-null, and request’s method is `GET` or `HEAD`, then throw a TypeError.”*